# Google compute instance is not accessible with external ip and port

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I created a google compute instance on https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/instances

After that I deployed a jar file embedded jetty server running on port 8082. I execute the jar file with java -jar command.

In VPC network I add a firewall rule to open port 8082.  Now if I try to access the google instance at port 8082 in web browser I am getting connection refused error. Below is the external ip address with port

http://35.184.211.81:8082

I don't know why above external ip is not working. If I open cloud shell and open web preview on port 8082 then I am able to access my web application on port 8082 below is the url

https://8082-dot-3144491-dot-devshell.appspot.com

It looks confusing. Above adress is showing that my application is deployed on google cloud instance but it is not accessible using external ip.

Comment: I don't know what the cause is, but "connection refused" means the IP is reachable, but the port is not allowed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved above issue by myself.

The problem was that I was using google cloud shell to deploy my application. I run the java -jar command in google cloud shell. I don't know why changes made or program executed in google cloud shell are temporary so that's the reason my application wasn't accessible on external IP.

I connected my instance using SSH, run the jar file and then my application is accessible on external IP with port. In https://console.cloud.google.com there is an option to connect the instance with SSH so i use that option.

Comment: Evidently in this case configuring the GCE host firewall wasn't an issue. But often this problem persists even when the GCE network firewall is configured correctly (to open the requested port), but the GCE host firewall is not configured correctly. Eg. a GCE CentOS host also requires running something like `sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --permanent --add-port=8082/tcp ; sudo firewall-cmd --reload` .